# .BBL without journaltitle

Tags: bibtex, journal

I look for the answer but can't find it... I am using TexMaker and Zotero for my bibliography.
When I am using bibtex, the `.bbl` file contain just the name, the title and the references. The is no journal title !!!

As an example :

in the `.bib` file :

```
@article{abreuJEAC572,
    title = {High frequency impedance spectroscopy study of passive films formed on {AISI} 316 stainless steel in alkaline medium},
    volume = {572},
    issn = {1572-6657},
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022072804000257},
    doi = {10.1016/j.jelechem.2004.01.015}, pages = {335-345},
    number = {2},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Electroanalytical Chemistry},
    author = {Abreu, C.M. and Cristóbal, M.J. and Losada, R. and Nóvoa, X.R. and Pena, G. and Pérez, M.C.},
    urldate = {2013-10-11},
    date = {2004-11-01},
    keywords = {{AISI} 316, Cyclic voltammetry, {EIS}, High frequency impedance, {XPS}}
}
```

give the .bbl :

```
\bibitem{abreuJEAC572}
C.M. Abreu, M.J. Cristóbal, R.~Losada, X.R. Nóvoa, G.~Pena, and M.C. Pérez.
\newblock High frequency impedance spectroscopy study of passive films formed
  on {AISI} 316 stainless steel in alkaline medium.
\newblock 572(2):335--345.
```

The protocole is : pdflatex + pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex

That's a big issue for me...
Thank you
Clément

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: try the field "journal" instead or "journaltitle".

Comment: The field name `journaltitle` is only used by `biblatex`, while `journal` is recognised by it and 'traditional' styles so it probably a lot 'safer'.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer We could get that one off the list.

Comment: @Johannes_B tomorrow, going to the donkeys now...

Answer (score 1):

Use the field "journal" instead or "journaltitle" with traditional bibtex, "journaltitle" is a biblatex field.